# ¿Como puedo mover arrays que están dentro de un array?

Tags: javascript, array

tengo un array con arrays

```
arr = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
```

pero quiero moverlos de posición para que queden de la siguiente manera:

```
arr = [[5,6],[3,4],[1,2]];
```

he buscado como poder hacer eso pero me no he podido encontrar solución, estoy buscando la solución con Javascript

Comment: Hola bienvenido a [es.SO], te invito a que te pases por el [tour] y también leas [ask] para futuras preguntas, procura siempre agregar al menos un [mcve]

Comment: OP deseas reversar los arreglos u ordenarnos de mayor a menor, tomando en cuenta el primer elemento de cada uno de los arreglos?

Comment: solo reversar... gracias Randall

Answer (score 5):

La solución es muy sencilla asumiendo que el valor de `arr` es `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`

```
var arr = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
arr = arr.reverse(); // [[5,6],[3,4],[1,2]]
```

Comment: Habría que mencionar que el OP ha declarado mal los array ¿no?

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, no está bien declarado el arreglo.

```js
arr = [1,2],[3,4],[5,6];
console.info(arr);
```

Obsérvese que la hacer clic en ejecutar sólo se muestra el primer elemento. Los siguientes han quedado como literales sin ser asignados a una una variable.

Debería declararse de la siguiente forma

```js
arr = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
console.info(arr);
```

Para cambiar el orden, usar la función reverse.

```js
arr = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
console.info(arr.reverse());
```